# If $a,b,c,d...$ be a series of quantities in G.P., show that the reciprocals of $a^2-b^2, b^2-c^2, c^2-d^2,...$ are also in G.P.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a,b,c,d...$ be a series of quantities in Geometrical Progression, show that the reciprocals of $a^2-b^2, b^2-c^2, c^2-d^2,...$ are also in Geometrical Progression; and find the sum of $n$ terms of this latter series in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Let $a=a, b=ar, c=ar^2, d=ar^3...$ where $r$ is the common ratio. Then:

$a^2-b^2 = a^2-a^2r^2 = a^2(1-r^2)$

$b^2-c^2=a^2r^2-a^2r^4=a^2r^2(1-r^2)$

$c^2-d^2=a^2r^4-a^2r^6=a^2r^4(1-r^2)$

Hence the series $a^2-b^2, b^2-c^2, c^2-d^2,...$ is in Geometrical Progression with a common ratio of $r^2$. The reciprocals are also in Geometrical Progression with a common ratio of $\dfrac{1}{r^2}$.

For the sum to $n$ terms:

First term = $\dfrac{1}{a^2(1-r^2)}$

Common ratio = $\dfrac{1}{r^2}$

Sum=$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{a^2(1-r^2)}[1-(r^2)^n]}{1-\dfrac{1}{r^2}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{a^2(1-r^2)}}{\dfrac{r^2-1}{r^2}}[1-(r^2)^n]=\dfrac{-r^2}{a^2(1-r^2)^2}(1-r^{2n})$

However the answer for the sum is given as $\dfrac{a^{2n}-b^{2n}}{b^{2n-2}(a^2-b^2)^2}$ so it seems I misunderstood the question and made wrong calculations as well. I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: "*find the sum of $n$ terms of this latter series* ***in terms of $a$ and $b$***" $\;-\;$ Your sum is *not* in terms of $a,b$. Substitute $\,r = \frac{b}{a}\,$ in your answer and see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation
$$
\text{Sum}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{a^2(1-r^2)}[1-(\color{red}{r^2})^n]}{1-\dfrac{1}{r^2}}
$$
should be
$$
\text{Sum}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{a^2(1-r^2)}\left[1-\left(\color{red}{\frac{1}{r^2}}\right)^n\right]}{1-\dfrac{1}{r^2}}\ .
$$
If you substitute $\ r=\frac{b}{a}\ $ into this latter identity, a little algebraic manipulation should reduce it to the given answer.

Comment: I just want to make sure about calculating with exponents: $\dfrac{-b^2}{b^{2n}}=-b^{2-2n}$ and $-b^{-(2-2n)}=\dfrac{-1}{b^{2n-2}}$. This is correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you've got it.